# how to check if any item is modified by list of people through work flow in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am very new to sharepoint workflow. I have a requirement where in a list, if an item is modified by someone other that a set of people(sharepoint group) a notification is to be set to that sharepoint group.
i am able to check if it is modified by single user but not multiple also not if i give group it is not working.

if currentItem:Modified by notequals groupname    is not working
Please help on how to check if any item is modified by list of people

Comment: I tried http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/how-check-if-item-modified-by-from-list-of-people-21014.aspx but could not get the result. i created a list with all the users in a column.

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint 2013 you can find if a user is member of a group using REST api like this :

```
http://Your.Site.Collection.Url/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('You group name')/CanCurrentUserViewMembership
```

The response will be true or false.

In your Sharepoint 2013 Workflow you can add an activity to call this service.

Then you will be able to know if the user is part of this group or not.

Hope this help.